# Firebase Crashlytic Errors: Android

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

We are using the latest Firebase Crashlytic dependency `com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.0.0`

The issues are:

```
W/OkHttpClient: A connection to https://firebase-settings.crashlytics.com/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?


E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Settings request failed.
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://firebase-settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/gmp/1:582811355855:android:a439b44cdd024799/settings?instance=de187b29e345c342d109ce02e794bff07e1613b0&build_version=7&display_version=1.2.0&source=1
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:251)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source:0)
        at j1.a.c(HttpGetRequest.java:80)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.network.a.a(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:113)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.d$a.b(SettingsController.java:199)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.d$a.a(SettingsController.java:192)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.g0.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.t$a$a.a(ExecutorUtils.java:64)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.c.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

The console also is not responding on enabling the feature unlike on other apps we worked on where it works pretty well.

[image]

Comment: The Crashlytic Console is now active, but I do not know the source of above error log if it is in the library or not.